# How do I connect all the little parts of the model to the main body?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh

[image]

currently it looks like this, all the blue lines unconnected to the main body underneath it. it makes whatever I do to it disconnect (i.e when using soft body, it makes everything disconnect as it falls onto the plane below).

In what fashion would I be able to connect them to the main body and prevent that from happening?

Comment: are these same objects in Outliner and are they geomertically linked?

Comment: they don't seem to be connected at all
https://imgur.com/a/CS8j2Ct

Comment: This is a suggestion without fully knowing what's happening.... A simple way might be to select each of them and parent them to the limb or body part they're supposed to be attached to.  If the model is rigged, then parent those components to their respective limb bones instead. (Pose mode)  This would keep them together as one, including when the main model falls.
If any of these sub-components have physics properties, remove them so the component is just scenery attached to the main's limb.